# How to set up SDL2 in MSYS2? I get error "undefined reference to 'WinMain'"

Tags: sdl, sdl-2, msys2

```
$ make
g++ main.cpp -I/mingw/include -L/mingw/lib -w -Wall -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -o test
/usr/lib/../lib/libmsys-2.0.a(libcmain.o): In function `main':
/msys_scripts/msys2-runtime/src/msys2-runtime/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:37: undefined reference to `WinMain'
/msys_scripts/msys2-runtime/src/msys2-runtime/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:37:(.text.startup+0x94): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `WinMain'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The difference between Mingw Tutorial and mine is '-lmingw32' option.

But There is no 'mingw32' file in MSYS2.

How to solve it?

Comment: What `g++ --version` outputs?

Comment: My g++ version is 6.3.0.

Comment: Thanks, but is there anything else? Does it say that it's a mingw version indeed? I'm asking just to be sure.

Comment: I have installed only msys2. Mingw isn't installed. There is a g++ in msys2.

Comment: @Gakgu there is `msys/gcc` and mingw versions named `mingw-w64-i686-gcc` and `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc`.
In your case you will need to install it and use MINGW32 or MINGW64 shell depending on arch.

Comment: @mati865 Thank! I solved it. I had not installed 'mingw-w64_x86_64-toolchain'. After install it, This is normally operating.

Comment: @mati865 I think you should post that as an answer for OP to accept it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat done.

Comment: @Gakgu I suggest you to press that green checkmark next to mati865's answer, which means that it solved your problem. This is how the site is supposed to work.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I hadn't known that. Thank you for informing me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 versions or gcc toolchain: Cygwin alike `msys/gcc` and native `mingw-w64-i686-gcc`, `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc`.

In your case you will need to install `mingw-w64-*` toolchain and use MINGW32 or MINGW64 shell depending on arch.